# Sending udp messages to local ips on disconnected NIC

Tags: c#, sockets

I have two IP adresses defined on a network card (NIC) (ex: 192.168.2.100, 192.168.2.101) on the same pc.

I am trying to send a datagram (udp) from one to another.
I get "address is not valid" when I create the sender socket and bind it to local EndPoint.
If I define them on a "Microsoft loopback adaptor" - it works
If I connect an eth cable to the NIC, even though the IP's are on the same card - it works

I've tried adding the addresses to static ARP table - doesn't work
I've tried defining a one of the addresses as a default gateway - doesn't work

I feel I'm missing some network definition or behavior I'm unfamiliar with (routing?)
(the code is very basic, and it works on loopback adapter, so its not an issue)

Comment: Is there any other machines on network that may have same address?  Turn of the two machines and then ping on network to see if you get any other responses.  I seen too many issues when duplicate IP addresses are assigned on a network.  If you still have issues there is not route to the device and a mask is wrong.  You may have a route that is blocking the ip.  The machines have to be assigned an ip that is inside the route addresses (including mask).

Comment: No other machine with these ips, tested with ping and also, these ips work when I put them on the ms loop back adaptor

Comment: You do not have a route between the two machines.  The loopback adaptor is creating a route but it is not a real route.  Get Ping working without a loopback adaptor.  Try ping in both directions.  Sometimes you have a forward route but no reverse route.

Comment: I think he is trying to bind to an IP address on an unplugged ethernet jack.

Comment: @Jerry Is it not possible even though the IP addresses are internal? (belong to the same network card)